# Different tooltip text on inner and outer div

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am using jquery tooltip plugin (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/ & http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) on two divs (outer and inner) and can't figure out how to get the inner div's tooltip displayed. The mouseover event must be getting propagated to the outer div and it always shows the tooltip for the outer one. Here's the sample code:

-- html

```
<div id="outer_div" style="width:100px;height:50px;background-color:blue;">
    &nbsp;
    <div id="inner_div" style="width:50px;height:20px;background-color:red;">
    &nbsp;
    </div>  
</div>
```

-- javascript

```
$("#outer_div").tooltip(
{
    bodyHandler: function() {
        return 'Outer';
    },
showURL: false,
track: true,
delay: 0,
showURL: false,
opacity: 1,
fixPNG: true,
top: -15,
left: 5
}
);

$("#inner_div").tooltip(
{
    bodyHandler: function() {
        return 'Inner';
    },
showURL: false,
track: true,
delay: 0,
showURL: false,
opacity: 1,
fixPNG: true,
top: -15,
left: 5
}
);
```

I want the tooltip to show 'Inner' when mouse is over the inner div and 'Outer' when it's anywhere else on the outer div. I can probably try to modify the plugin itself to stop event propagation but not sure if I want to go there yet. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think this might be an issue with the plugin itself. If you add   event.stopPropagation(); right at the beginning of handle(event) function jquery.tooltip.min.js, then it works just fine. Will submit this request to the developers